# Adding a record to a has_many_and_belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two Rails models of the form:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many_and_belongs_to :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many_and_belongs_to :users
end
```

I have a migration which creates the tags_users table.

How do I add a record to the tags_users table? (Tags and Users are unique)

I've trying doing a

```
users.tag_ids << new_tag
```

but that does not seem to work. Any pointers are welcome

Comment: `has_many_and_belongs_to` - is that [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many)?

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to achieve that, e.g:

```
u = User.first
t = Tag.create(name: 't')
u.tag_ids << t.id

# or:

u = User.first
t = Tag.new(name: 't')
u.tags << t
```

You can't call `collection_singular_ids` (`tag_ids` in this case) on a collection. It is worth noting that having [HABTM](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) association, you do not have access to the join model explicitly (e.g `TagUser`).